# Assert inferred type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, error-handling, type-inference, narrowing

I'm looking for a nice way to assert the type TypeScript inferred for a particular variable. This is what I am using right now:

```js
function assertType<T>(value: T) { /* no op */ }

assertType<SomeType>(someValue);
```

This is particularly useful when I want to make sure I cover all possible values returned by a function. For instance:

```js
function doSomething(): "ok" | "error" { ... }

const result = doSomething();

if(result === "error") { return; }

assertType<"ok">(result);

// do something only if result is OK
```

This ensures that adding new variants to the sum `"ok" | "error"`, like `"timeout"`, will trigger a type error.

The `assertType` solution works in practice, but I find it unfortunate to have a noop call, and I'm hoping there may be a native way to do this, for instance:

```js
if(result === "error") { return; }

<"ok">result // magic

// do something only if result is OK
```

Comment: You might be able to write `result satisfies "ok";`; does that work for you?  Note that this is still a “no-op” appearance of `result` in your code.

Comment: No that's exactly what I was looking for! This is completely erased with no consequence on the generated JS. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `satisfies` keyword to ensure the type is correct:

```
function check(result: "error" | "ok") {
  if (result === "error") { return; }

  result satisfies "ok"

}

function check2(result: "error" | "ok" | "warning") {
  if (result === "error") { return; }

  result satisfies "ok" // ERROR here

}
```